Copy geometryless tables from Microsoft SQL Server using gdal
I need to copy tables from a Microsoft SQL Server.
I can connect and list tables with:
ogrinfo.exe -al -so MSSQL:server=1.2.3.4.5;database=somedb;trusted_connection=no;UID=user;PWD=password

But only tables with geometries are listed.
I can copy one table to geopackage with:
ogr2ogr C:\GIS\data\testdata\test\data.gpkg MSSQL:server=1.2.3.4.5;database=somedb;trusted_connection=no;UID=user;PWD=password schema.table_with_geometries

But when I try to copy a table (that I know exist) without geometry I get

ERROR 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer
'schema.table_without_geometry'!

Is it possible to copy geometryless tables?
